# Exclude docker directory in .net core application

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I have problems with running .net core app on my Debian 9. All .net core versions below 2.0 preview returns 
"**Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80131500**" error during execute dotnet new, restore or e.g --version.

.NET core 2.0 preview works correctly but framework doesn't want to cooperate with JwtBearer - becasue Bearer has 1.1.2 version and dotnet returns 
"**Downgrade package detected bla bla....**"
(Maybe you have idea how to build app with downgrade package?)

So I decided to move project to docker. 
I downloaded docker with .net core 1.1. I created docker-compose file, where I add a volume mount to docker see my application.
Everything works correctly, but with one small exception.

When I execute dotnet restore, build and run on my docker, everyting is beeing override, so my Visual Studio Code immidietly shows me warrining "Unresolved dependencies ...." and all references to dotnet namespaces, class etc are highlighted in red.

How I can fix it?

Below is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  webapi:
        build: .
        command: "/bin/bash"
        container_name: webapi
        volumes:
            - /home/pb/docker-test/docker-compose:/app
            - /home/pb/docker-test/docker-compose/Evento.Api/obj/
        ports:
          - "5000:80"
        tty: true
```

**/home/pb/docker-test/docker-compose/Evento.Api/obj/** I think that this directory makes problems becouse contains a few path which are changing after dotnet restore.

I tried to exclude that directory in this way, but it doesn't work. Event if direcotry is not mounted, dotenet creates it after dotnet restore, and override on host.

Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build
WORKDIR /app
```